# How to combine macros into one macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 different sheets in one workbook and every sheet has tables that needs to filter by customer column and copy to another workbook.

How to combine those macros into one so I don't have to multiply that macro 20-30 times to get all filtered data from every sheet to another workbook?

```
Sub sheet1()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Workbook

    Sheets("SHANA").Activate

    LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Range("A1:j" & LastRow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="customerA"

    Selection.Copy

    Set ws = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...test.xlsx")
    Worksheets("SHANA ").Paste

    Selection.AutoFilter

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ws.Save

End Sub
```

Next macros are same except sub sheet 1 is 2 and so on.

Sheets("SHANA") is called LHANA and next macro PHANA and Worksheets ("SHANA") is LHANA and so on.

Also Customer field can some sheet be in 6 column and Customers changes.

Customer change does not matter as all customers have their own workbook.

I have no error messages in that code.